# Produce JSON by RESTful web service in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

**My problem:** I don't returns Json but an array.

So, I will wish Json return:

**My repository interface:**

```
public interface SuiRepository extends JpaRepository<Folder, Integer>{
@Query("...")
    public List<Folder> data();
}
```

**My method:**

```
@Override
    public List<Folder> getFolder(){
        List<Folder> s = folderRepository.data();

        return s;

    }
```

**My Rest Service:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/folders", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public  List<Folder> getFolders() {
        return iUd.getFolders();
    }
```

**My Folder class**

```
Entity
     public class Folder implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int idFolder; 
        private String comments;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="IdFile")
        private File file;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="username")
        private User user;

     **Getters&Setters...**

}
```

**The current return:**

```
[["Ban","dee","dede@gmail.com",1,"xx","Emb"],["Cin","mis","sse@gmail.com",1,"yy","Ns"]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does your Folder class look like?

Comment: You are getting `JSON`, what you posted is 100% valid `JSON`! What do you want? An array of `Object` instead of an `Array` of `Array`? Based on your code and annotations it does not look like you have even looked at the documentation a single time, you have annotations that make no sense based on the methods they are annotating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [springboot jackson returns array instead of proper json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954728/springboot-jackson-returns-array-instead-of-proper-json-object)

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: Are you expecting something like
[
{id:1,
name:"test",
comments:"something"},
{id:2,
name:"test1",
comments:"something1"}
]

Are you expetring list of your objects like above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor annotated with @JsonCreator in you entity:

Ex

```
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String name;
    String phone;
    String password;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                @JsonProperty("phone") String phone) {

        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;

    }

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check you have the following dependency in your `pom.xml` ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you can have more information about how Spring boot handles Java object to JSON on spring boot website : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

> The Greeting object must be converted to JSON. Thanks to Spring’s HTTP
>   message converter support, you don’t need to do this conversion
>   manually. Because [Jackson 2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) is on the classpath, Spring’s
>   `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is automatically chosen to convert
>   the Greeting instance to JSON.

Comment: I put this dependence, but it still does not work :(

Comment: What spring boot project did you start from ? Can you please provide your `pom.xml` in your request ? Also, you should check the following Spring Boot guide : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: why do you think an `XML` data format provider has anything to do with `JSON`?

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this one in controller :

@RequestMapping(value="/folders", method= RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Folder> getFolders()
{
  HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
  List<Folder> listFol=iUd.getFolders();
  return new ResponseEntity<HawkeyesResponse>(listFol,httpStatus);
}
```

In class level add this annotation :

```
@RestController
```