# springboot jackson returns array instead of proper json object

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, output

I have the following controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testService/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<TestBean> test(@RequestParam Map<String,String> testReq)     {
...
List<Test> objList=testRepository.test();
testBean.setObjects(objList);
...
return new ResponseEntity<TestBean>(testBean, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

TestBean holds a list of Test objects(with getters/setters and some other attributes) as below

```
private List<Test> objects;
```

Test class is defined as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5319848003675140194L;
@JsonIgnore
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="TEST_ID")
Integer testId;
...
```

test() method is defined as below.

```
@Query(value="SELECT ...", nativeQuery=true)
List<Test> test();
```

The json output I see is as below

```
{"requestId":"testRequestId","objects":[[1,"Test name"],[2,"Test name2"]],"status":"Success"}
```

Other things being okay, my question is why is the objects list being output in that way instead of like this

```
{"testId":1,"testName":"Test name"}
```

For another similar objects that I am using I see the output as expected(in proper json format).

Please note that I have not copied the actual code, but typed the code with changed names, so please ignore any syntax errors that you may see in the code.

Could someone please advise on how can I get a proper json in the output?

Comment: We need more info about your `Test` and `TestBean` classes. Do any of these classes contain Jackson annotations? The array serialization happens when the `BeanAsArraySerializer` is used, which might be activated if you have certain `@JsonFormat` annotations.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's very weird that your ID is also in that array, since you added a `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the `testId` field (unless it's a different number in the response).

Comment: There are no extra annotations on the Test class other than what I have already mentioned.
And below is the only annotation on TestBean.

    `@JsonPropertyOrder({ "requestId", "objects" })
    public class TestBean extends ResourceSupport  {`

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue. The problem was I was using a JPA repository class that was created for a different object.
I created a new JPA repository class for Test object and it works fine now, I am getting correctly formed json output.
Thanks